# How can I set the TIMESTAMP in openschift table to the local time

Tags: java

I am trying to set the the created_at column time of this  `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my table  on `OPENSHIFT` to the local time of `Copenhagen` also from `2015-05-16 12:44:42` to `2015-05-16 18:44:42` How can I set the time in the openshift server to my localtime?

I appreciate any help.

```
   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kopenhagen");
    calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

   System.out.println(calendar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp has no timezone field. It is just value of the time. Set it implicitly in your sql statement as value and not use database time (like sysdate for Oracle).